# page.DataContext not inherited from parent Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext, msdn

I have a Page `page` in a Frame `frame`, with `frame.DataContext = "foo"`.

- `(page.Parent as Frame).DataContext` is `"foo"`. **ok**
- BindingExpression for `page.DataContext` is `null` (also forced with ClearValue). **ok**
- `page.DataContext` is `null`. **but I expected "foo"!**

Why isn't the DataContext inherited? As far as I [understand](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9d96e53d-94cc-4089-a51d-944d3a362870/) the Frame *sandboxes* the content. But I couldn't find any documentation of this behavior - can anyone point me to a place where this is mentioned?

Comment: The BindingExpresion is not passed over to the child item, but the DataContext is. Did you check the DataContext property itself?

Comment: Yes, DataContext is also null. It remains `null` even after calling ClearValue on it as well.

Comment: Thanks for asking this :0)  As a note changing the datacontext from the user control hosting the frame after everything has loaded (*after* the loaded event) causes the page to inherit the new datacontext (have to null clear & set it back to original, or not set until after the loaded event has finished).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To answer your question about documentation of this behavior: It's not Microsoft documentation, but I have a couple of WPF books that both mention this.

"[Essential Windows Presentation Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374479)" says: (pp. 160-161)

> There are two interesting models for hosting navigable content: isolated hosting and integrated hosting.
>
> With **isolated hosting** the content is not trusted and is run in a completely isolated (sandboxed) environment. This is how WPF content is hosted when running in the system Web browser as a XAML Browser Application. For navigation to another application or HTML content, this isolated hosting model is supported with a `Frame` object.
>
> **Integrated hosting,** in which we want the content to behave as part of our application, is not supported at all in the system. When `Frame` navigates to content within the application, we get an odd hybrid of isolated and integrated behavior. `Frame` isolates its content from its style (and its parent's style), but not from the application's style. Events don't bubble from the content in `Frame`; however, the objects are accessible from the `Content` property (meaning that they aren't isolated in a security sense).
>
> For all these reasons, `Frame` is most useful when we're working with external content, but it can be carefully used for application content.

That's all it has to say -- nothing about property inheritance.

"[Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) says (p. 95):

> The `Frame` control holds arbitrary content, just like all other content controls, but it isolates the content from the rest of the UI. For example, properties that would normally be inherited down the element tree stop when they reach the `Frame`.

Answer (score 33):

You didn't specifically ask *how* you could make this work, only *why* it doesn't by default. However, if you do want your Pages to inherit the Frame's DataContext, you can do this:

In XAML:

```
<Frame Name="frame"
       LoadCompleted="frame_LoadCompleted"
       DataContextChanged="frame_DataContextChanged"/>
```

In codebehind:

```
private void frame_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFrameDataContext(sender, e);
}
private void frame_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFrameDataContext(sender, e);
}
private void UpdateFrameDataContext(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var content = frame.Content as FrameworkElement;
    if (content == null)
        return;
    content.DataContext = frame.DataContext;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To build upon @Joe-White's answer for those who want to know of ways to make the `Frame` cascade the `DataContext`, I'll mention that this can also be performed in XAML only.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_FrameCP" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="NavigationUIVisibility" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FrameNavChromeTemplateKey}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="JournalOwnership" Value="OwnsJournal"/>
                    <Condition Property="NavigationUIVisibility" Value="Automatic"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FrameNavChromeTemplateKey}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

For those that are new to WPF, you can put this XAML in the `App.xaml` file so that it will override all `Frame` controls in your application that pick up the default style.  This means you don't have to write specific code-behind each time you use a new `Frame`.

I used the VisualStudio 2015 Visual Designer (see pic below) to create the bulk of the XAML above and then added the `DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"` to perform the cascade.

[image: VS2015 designer]

Comment: Did not work for me.  I received an exception "Unable to case object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate'.