# Frame navigation - DataContext not inherited

Tags: wpf, navigation, frame, datacontext

I have a XAML file representing the main window of a WPF application.
Now I want this window to display content that is specified by another XAML file.
This works, but the `DataContext` is lost in the C# code of my `UserControl`.

I think the `<Frame Source=....>` is breaking the logical tree of WPF in some way.
I'd like to have the same behavior as if `<Frame Source=....>` was simply substituted by the *Content1.xaml* file content, i.e. that the `DataContext` of the surrounding `Window` class is inherited to the `UserControl`.

Is there a simple way to overcome this issue?
All [solutions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27432/Artificial-Inheritance-Contexts-in-WPF) that I found seem like overkill.

**Pseudocode**

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window ....>
    <Frame Source="Content1.xaml" />
</Window>
```

*Content1.xaml*

```
<UserControl ....>
  <!-- Content goes here -->
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Have a look at the response from Joe White here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame

Comment: @Michael Joe White's solution works for me. I think you can post the link as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Joe White's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame) solves the problem.

Quoting from his answer:

In XAML:

```
<Frame Name="frame"
       LoadCompleted="frame_LoadCompleted"
       DataContextChanged="frame_DataContextChanged"/>
```

In codebehind:

```
private void frame_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFrameDataContext(sender, e);
}
private void frame_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateFrameDataContext(sender, e);
}
private void UpdateFrameDataContext(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var content = frame.Content as FrameworkElement;
    if (content == null)
        return;
    content.DataContext = frame.DataContext;
}
```

Comment: You have an issue with the arguments (which are not used anyway).