# UserControl VS Page in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm on writing a simple application, it has a menu and when user choices each `MenuItem`, i want to change my window's content to display the selected content.

i have two option to that.

1. i can add a `<Frame></Frame>` to my window and write some pages.
2. i can write some `UserControls` and put them in a `ContentControl`

as user fires `MenuItem` click event.

so I'm confused to select the right choice for this purpose.

Comment: Frame/Page have some gotchas, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame. If you don't need isolation specifically, then stick to ContentControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation can be succefully implemented by using Frame/Pages or ContentControl/Views. It is a matter of choice.

However, Frame/Page have some gotchas, e.g. [page.DataContext not inherited from parent Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame)

If you don't need isolation specifically, then stick to ContentControl. Navigation in [prism](/questions/tagged/prism) framework is built with regions which are located in different type of controls (e.g. ContentControl, TabControl), not Frame ([see docs](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Navigation.html#view-based-navigation))

---

one more approach for simple navigation is ViewModel based.

Examples:

[WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views)

[Navigation with MVVM by Rachel Lim](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) (external)