# How to correctly setup datacontext within WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following question:

I'm having a couple of Pages, one of the pages is called: *StartschermCursussen.xaml* and is used in a frame inside my *MainWindow.xaml*.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="ClientWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClientWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="sideWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" Panel.ZIndex="50"/>
        <Frame Name="mainWindow" Margin="50,0,0,0" Source="Pages/StartschermCursussen.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Inside my *StartschermCursussen.xaml.cs* I'm having my **Datacontext** that is connected to an 'Container' class that holds references and has properties that are connected to my ViewModels.

**StartschermCursussen.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class StartschermCursussen : Page
{
      public StartschermCursussen()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          KeepAlive = true;
          DataContext = Container;
      }

      public ItemsContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

**Container class**

```cs
public class ItemsContainer
{
    public FilterItem FilterItem { get; set; }
    public List<CourseDTO> courses { get; set; } = new List<CourseDTO>();
    public List<IconItem> IconList { get; set; } = new List<IconItem>();
    public ItemsContainer()
    {
       //One of my ViewModels
       FilterItem = new FilterItem();
    }
}
```

Now, I'm having another page called *DetailsCursus.xaml.cs*. In that page I'm trying to get specific properties from my ViewModels through databinding in *xaml* to apply changes to them and show them to the end-user etc.
One way how I did this is through constructor overloading inside my *StartschermCursussen.xaml.cs*.

**StartschermCursussen.xaml.cs** (Sending data from DataContext  -> **DetailsCursus.xaml.cs**)

```cs
 private void menuItemDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
        var item = (DataGrid)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
        CourseDTO toDeleteFromBindedList = (CourseDTO)item.SelectedCells[0].Item;

        //Here I'm sending the data through constructor
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new DetailsCursus(toDeleteFromBindedList, Container.IconList));
}
```

**DetailsCursus.xaml.cs**

```cs
 public DetailsCursus(CourseDTO data, List<IconItem> iconList)
 {
     object[] items = { data, iconList };
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = items;
 }
```

In the above code snippet I put incoming data in an Array and then linked it to my Datacontext. But I have the feeling that this is not the correct way to get data from your Datacontext.

The code snippet below shows how I get to the data in the Datacontext and I show this in the *ItemSource* of a *ComboBox*. It works and returns me the results but I feel like I'm doing this the wrong way.

**DetailsCursus.xaml**

```cs
<ComboBox Width="100" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=[1]}" DisplayMemberPath="IconName" />
```

Would someone please explain to me how to correctly use the Datacontext within the WPF Pages.

**Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

`object[]` is certainly unconventional choice for DataContext.

You can create a special named class for DetailsCursus view (pretty common, must-do in MVVM pattern), which will do wonders to readability:

```
 public class DetailsCursusViewModel
 {
     public CourseDTO SelectedCourse { get; set; }
     public List<IconItem> IconList { get; set; }
 }

 private void menuItemDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
    var dg = (DataGrid)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
    var toDeleteFromBindedList = (CourseDTO)dg.SelectedCells[0].Item;

    var viewModel = new DetailsCursusViewModel
    {
        SelectedCourse = toDeleteFromBindedList ,
        IconList = Container.IconList
    };
    var page = new DetailsCursus(viewModel);
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
 }

 public DetailsCursus(DetailsCursusViewModel viewModel)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = viewModel; // fix bindings after this!
 }
```

I also suggest to explore [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) pattern in WPF, and also check alternatives for navigation ([UserControl VS Page in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408072/usercontrol-vs-page-in-wpf))

Comment: This is the explanation I needed! Thanks you sir @ASh!