# Can't bind ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I made a class for store ViewModels

```cs
internal class Locator
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
}
```

And added it to application resources

```xml
<Application x:Class="Marathon.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Marathon"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <local:Locator x:Key="Locator" x:Name="Locator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then bound it Locator to the Main Window

```xml
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="350" MinWidth="525">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Content="{Binding Page}"></Frame>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It works.

When I add a binding (DataContext) to a Page. It throws an exception (`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`, `Cannot find resource named 'Locator'.`).

```xml
<Page x:Class="App.Pages.StartPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel}"
      Title="StartPage">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

How to bind DataContext to a page?

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3621424/1506454

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `x:Name` in your `App.xaml` declaration of the locator instance, `x:Key` is sufficient

Comment: Thanks for this issue, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can it be because I don't use DI and just create the ViewModel via a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The error most occurs if and when you instantiate the `Page` itself in the view model.

A view model shouldn't create `Page` objects. Try to return a `Uri` instead and bind to the `Source` property instead:

```
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="350" MinWidth="525">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Source="{Binding Page}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This should work:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Uri Page { get; } = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```