# ContentControl with DataTemplate is not displaying anything (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

In my MainView, there is a Frame containing a ContentControl supposed to show a View depending on a ViewModel set in MainViewModel.
However, nothing shows on my MainView. Any idea why?

**MainView**

```
<Grid>
    <Frame HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Frame.Content>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding TestViewContext}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
                        <local:TestView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private TestViewModel _testViewContext;
    public TestViewModel TestViewContext
    {
        get { return _testViewContext; }
        set { _testViewContext = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestViewContext)); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TestViewContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
}
```

**TestView**
Just a red colored Page

**TestViewModel**

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frame` is a bit special. Normally, child controls inherit the `DataContext` of their parent. However, with a `Frame`, the children do not inherit the `DataContext`. As a result, your `ContentControl` has a `DataContext` of `null`.

To verify this, give your `ContentControl` a name like the following:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl" Content="{Binding TestViewContext}">
```

Then in the constructor of your `MainView`, check the `DataContext` as follows:

```
public MainView()
{
    // Other code

    // Set a breakpoint here and view the DataContext
    var dataContext = MyContentControl.DataContext;
}
```

For further reading, you could read the following post:
[page.DataContext not inherited from parent Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame)

Also, as a side note, `Frame` intended use was setting the `Source` property to an external file. As you may have noticed, in order to set child content in xaml, you need to specify `<Frame.Content>` unlike other controls.